# SSDT: Error: Deploy72002: Identifiers must include at least one name (for example, MyTable). Done building project "Common.sqlproj" -- FAILED

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, publish, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

While i'm trying to PUBLISH my SSDT DB projects getting the below error:

> Identifiers must include at least one name (for example, MyTable)"

We need to deploy 65 SSDT projects and unable to fix this issue.

Resolutions tried :

- Deleting .refactorlog file
- modified schemas in .refactorlog file also
- Deploying through "SQLPACKAGE.exe" .
- Deploying DACPAC through SQL server.

Comment: Please check that all the `$(...)` variables have values assigned in sqlproj and publish.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. In my case I could not do schema compare nor could I publish a database. After some trial and error I found the problem went away two different ways, one was removing the refactorlog.sql file from the database project and the other solution was that the target database was missing the dbo.__RefactorLog table so I created it in the target database. In both cases I was able to once again schema compare and publish as the error stopped presenting itself. My preferred solution was to add the dbo.__refactorlog table to the target database.